# How can I sort JSON objects for a leaderboard?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to sort the following JSON with my jquery and make a leader board out of their 'money' I want the #1 leader to be the one with the most money and the last place person the one with the least. I've tried several ways of doing this including a sort function but I can't seem to get it to work. Can you explain the best way of doing this?

```
    {
id: "3",
username: "test3",
money: "500",
state_id: "0",
state_name: "none",
state_abbrev: "none",
bets_amount_total: 0,
bets_amount_won: 0,
bets_amount_lost: 0
},
{
id: "4",
username: "johnny",
money: "500",
state_id: "0",
state_name: "none",
state_abbrev: "none",
bets_amount_total: 0,
bets_amount_won: 0,
bets_amount_lost: 0
},
```

here's my code:

```
    getLeaders().done(function(results){

            $.each(results, function(i, leaderStats){
                var leaderUser = leaderStats.username;
                var money = leaderStats.money

            $('#leader-container').append('\
            <div>\
            <div class="leaderboard-rank">rank</div>\
            <div class="leaderboard-name">' + leaderUser +'</div>\
            <div class="leaderboard-score">'+ money +'</div>\
            </div>\
            ');

            });
        });
```

Comment: "including a sort function" seems promising - can you post it?

Comment: @barmar how do I do that?

Comment: I misread your JSON, I thought it was an object whose keys were the IDs, not an array of objects. It would help if you showed the whole JSON, not just an excerpt.

Comment: If it's an array of objects, the normal `Array.prototype.sort` method should work fine.

Comment: @Barmar it's an array of objects

Comment: @Barmar can you explain how to use that?

Comment: Isn't it explained in the linked question?

Comment: @Barmar I cant seem to sort in an each

Comment: you don't sort in the `.each()`, you sort *before* it.

Comment: `results.sort(...); $.each(results, ...)`